# Convert string of time to cleaner format

Tags: javascript, regex, string, time

There's usually some magical way to do something in javascript.

Take for example the string

`10h49m02s`

and wanting to convert it to

`10 hours, 49 minutes, 2 seconds`

while avoid empty hours/minutes/seconds

eg2

`00h10m20s`

This is what I'm doing which is probably hilarious

```
var arr = time.split('');
var hourMaj = arr[0];
var hourMin = arr[1];
var minMaj = arr[3];
var minMin = arr[4];
var secMaj = arr[6];
var secMin = arr[7];

var str = "";

if(hourMaj !== '0'){
   str += hourMaj;
   str += hourMin;
}else if (hourMin !== '0'){
  str += hourMin;
}
if(hourMaj !== '0' || hourMin !== '0')
  str += "hours, ";

... and on
```

Comment: Is there a question? You can use various methods for parsing strings, e.g. regular expressions, but your approach of tokenising then processing is fundamentally OK. You can make it more efficient though.

Comment: Sorry, my question should have included a question - I was looking for a regex really but was clueless how to start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually use a regex to match your values and replace `h`, `m` and `s` with expanded words only if the captured texts are not zeros, like this:

```js
var re = /\b0*(\d{1,2})h0*(\d{1,2})m0*(\d{1,2})s\b/g; 
var str = '10h49m02s';
var str2 = '00h10m20s';

function func(match, h, m, s) {
  var p = '';
  if (h !== '0') {
    p += h + " hours"
  }
  if (m !== '0') {
    p += (p.length > 0 ? ", " : "") + m + " minutes"
  }
  if (s !== '0') {
    p += (p.length > 0 ? ", " : "") + s + " seconds"
  }
  return p;
}

var res = str.replace(re, func);
document.write(res + "<br/>");
res = str2.replace(re, func);
document.write(res);
```

The regex  - `\b0*(\d{1,2})h0*(\d{1,2})m0*(\d{1,2})s\b` - matches:

- `\b` - word boundary
- `0*` - 0 or more leading zeros
- `(\d{1,2})` - hours, 1 or 2 digits
- `h0*` - `h` literally and 0 or more zeros
- `(\d{1,2})` - minutes, 1 or 2 digits
- `m0*` - `m` literally and 0 or more zeros
- `(\d{1,2})` - seconds, 1 or 2 digits
- `s\b` - `s` at the end of the "word".

Comment: Thanks, regex are intensely powerful

Comment: They are even more powerful when using with language-specific RegExp methods, and in this case, the `func` callback function is worth attention. It lets manipulate the replacement process quite nicely.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to stribizhev's answer, but with a much simpler regular expression. I've used *reduce* but a for loop is no more code and would probably be faster:

```js
function parseTime(s) {

  // Match sequences of numbers or letters
  var b = s.match(/\d+|[a-z]+/gi);
  var words = {h:'hour', m:'minute', s:'second'};
  var result;

  // If some matches found
  if (b) {

    // Do replacement
    result = b.reduce(function(acc, p, i) {

      // Only include values that aren't zero
      // and skip letters - +p => NaN
      if (+p) {

        // Change letters to words, add plural and store in array
         acc.push(+p + words[b[i+1]] + (p==1? '' : 's'));
      }

      // Pass the accumulator array to the next iteration
      return acc;
    },[])
  }

  // Format the result
  return result.join(', ');
}

document.write(parseTime('00h00m02s') + '<br>');
document.write(parseTime('10h40m02s') + '<br>');
document.write(parseTime('10h00m51s') + '<br>');
document.write(parseTime('01h32m01s'));
```

Comment: Thanks, never seen reduce before. Really interesting method. Not understanding `if(+p)`

Comment: *p* is a string, the unary + operator converts it to a Number so if it converts to zero or `NaN` (e.g. it's `"h"`), the *push* step is skipped.